# How do I find the degree of a multivariable polynomial automatically?

Tags: polynomials

I have a very simple question which appears not to have already been answered on this forum. Is there built-in functionality that returns the degree of a multivariable polynomial? For example if the polynomial is

```
s1 + s2^2 s3 + s3^2 s4^7
```

I want *Mathematica* to return 9. If there is no automatic solution, could somebody please suggest a simple (and fast) implementation?

EDIT: I removed my "solution" because it actually only works for simple examples. I tested out the four solutions presented so far on a degree 20 polynomial in 6 variables (`ByteCount[poly] = 2006352`). I used `AbsoluteTiming` to determine that the answer I chose is the fastest, with a run-time of 53.06 s for 1000 evaluations. This is quite a bit faster than the closest competitor's run-time of 283.76 s for 1000 evaluations.

UPDATE: I tested the improved version of the solution (the one with random reals) and found that the run-time is now slightly worse but still far better than the competition at 90.52 s for 1000 evaluations.

Comment: It is written that it is an undecidable problem to find the degree of multivariate polynomial ? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialDegree.html

Comment: @Smilia, that does not necessarily mean it's impossible to determine the degree of a given specific polynomial. What you were quoting is related to the [constant problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_problem), and not being able to determine the highest-degree term in general is equivalent to not being able to determine if the requisite coefficients are zero.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps

```
 Exponent[# /. Thread[Variables[#] -> \[FormalX]], \[FormalX]] &[s1 + s2^2 s3 + s3^2 s4^7]
 (* 9 *)
```

?

**UPDATE:** As noted by Daniel in the comments, the original function gives the wrong result if cancellations occur after all variables are replaced by the same symbol. To fix this issue, one can modify the function as

```
Exponent[# /. ((# -> \[FormalX] RandomReal[]) & /@ Variables[#]), \[FormalX]] &
```

(per Daniel's suggestion), or as

```
Max@Exponent[MonomialList[#] /.Thread[Variables[#] -> \[FormalX]], \[FormalX]]&
```

Comment: In practice, one would use a formal variable for safety...

Comment: @J.M. thank you; updated using your suggestion.

Comment: Use random reals times `\[FormalX]` to avoid accidental cancellations.

Comment: @Daniel, great point! thank you.

Comment: I learned this the hard way, trying to figure out why a definite integral I knew we were unable to do was instead giving zero. Now zero is, for a number of reasons, a "common" wrong answer in that part of the computational world. But this one was not caused by any of the usual suspects. The thing was split into two pieces, both of which failed. You can guess what `$Failed-$Failed` gives.

Comment: Also safe would be : `Exponent[# /. Thread[Variables[#] -> (\[FormalX] Variables[#]]), \[FormalX]] &[s1 + s2^2 s3 + s3^2 s4^7]`

Answer (score 9):

```
Max[Plus @@@ CoefficientRules[#][[All, 1]]] &@ (s1 + s2^2 s3 + s3^2 s4^7)
```

=> 
9

**Edit**

[J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) (in a comment) suggests the following neat modification:

```
Max[Cases[CoefficientRules[s1 + s2^2 s3 + s3^2 s4^7], v_?VectorQ :> Total[v], 2]]
```

Comment: Alternatively: `Max[Cases[CoefficientRules[s1 + s2^2 s3 + s3^2 s4^7], v_?VectorQ :> Total[v], 2]]`

Comment: That's a very elegant method

Comment: This is the method I was about to add, +1.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an implementation adapted from a routine by Eric Weisstein:

```
AlgebraicDegree[eqn_, vars_List] := Max[Total[
      GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[eqn /. Equal :> Subtract, vars][[1, All, 1]], {2}]]

AlgebraicDegree[eqn_] := AlgebraicDegree[eqn, Variables[eqn]]
```

Example:

```
AlgebraicDegree[s1 + s2^2 s3 + s3^2 s4^7]
   9
```

Answer (score 2):

OP's `MonomialList[]` approach could certainly be simplified somewhat:

```
Max[Composition[Total[#[[All, 2]]] &, Rest, FactorList] /@
    MonomialList[s1 - s2^2 s3 + 3 s3^2 s4^7]]
   9
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
In[1]:= ClearSystemCache[]

In[2]:= Through[Thread[
            {
                    (*kglr*)Exponent[# /. ((# -> \[FormalX] RandomReal[])& /@ \
        Variables[
                        #]), \[FormalX]]&
                    ,
                    (*Rolf Mertig*)Max @ Exponent[MonomialList[#] /. \
        Thread[Variables[
                        #] -> \[FormalX]], \[FormalX]]&
                    ,
                    (*user1066*)Max[Plus @@@ CoefficientRules[#][[All, 1]]]&
                    ,
                    (*J. M.'s lack of A.I.１*)Max[Cases[CoefficientRules[#], \
        v_
                        ?VectorQ :> Total[v], 2]]&
                    ,
                    (*J. M.'s lack of \
        A.I.２*)Max[Total[GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[
                        # /. Equal :> Subtract, Variables[#]][[1, All, 1]], \
        {2}]]&
                    ,
                    (*J. M.'s lack of A.I.３*)Max[Composition[Total[#[[All, \
        2]]
                        ]&, Rest, FactorList] /@ MonomialList[#]]&
                    ,
                    (*Mine:*) (Plus @@ # ~ Exponent ~ Variables @ #& /@ \
        MonomialList
                         @ # // Max)&
                } /* EchoTiming
        ][(w + x + y + z) ^ 1*^2]]
>> 0.0001861
>> 9.57767
>> 4.6006
>> 5.28342
>> 3.61365
>> 19.1789
>> 15.815

Out[2]= {100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100}
```

Unfortunately, my implementation is rather inefficient. (Why?)