# How can I get an exponent vector from monomials?

Tags: polynomials

I am trying to get an exponent vector from a list of monomials. I am using the `CoefficientRules` command; however, it is returning a list that includes the coefficients of the monomial. I don't need the coefficient and need to remove it before I can use the exponent vector, however I am finding this quite difficult.

```
poly = x^2 + 2 x*y + y^2;
monomialList = MonomialList[poly];
alpha = CoefficientRules[monomialList]

{{{2, 0} -> 1}, {{1, 1} -> 2}, {{0, 2} -> 1}}
```

Is there a way to remove the -> and the value that follows it, or a better way to generate the exponent vector?

Answer (score 3):

One quick method (also used in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14932)):

```
GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[x^2 + 2 x*y + y^2, {x, y}][[1, All, 1]]
   {{2, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 2}}
```

Another one, based on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14933):

```
Cases[CoefficientRules[x^2 + 2 x*y + y^2], v_?VectorQ, 2]
```

Comment: That solution is excellent, however is there a way to modify the second answer to accept the list of monomials instead of the original polynomial?

Comment: Sure, do something like `Map[Cases[CoefficientRules[#], v_?VectorQ, 2] &, (* monomials *)]`...