# Degree of multivariate polynomials with weights

Tags: polynomials

I have a slightly different question than this post:

[How do I find the degree of a multivariable polynomial automatically?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14925/how-do-i-find-the-degree-of-a-multivariable-polynomial-automatically/136069#136069)

I would like to compute the degree of a multivariate polynomial but with respect to a gradation that is I put weights on variables to compute the order.

For instance, $p=x^2y + z^3 + y^4$ with the gradation $(1,1,2)$ for $(x,y,z)$
is of degree $6$.

I have that to compute the order of a monomial $x^i y^j z^k$ I apply

```
ordMonome[mon]:=Log[mon]/.{x->Exp[1],y->Exp[1],z->Exp[2]};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

[Daniel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) provided a proper solution in the comments.  I am including it here (and leading with it) as he did not choose to post an answer of his own.

```
p = x^2 y + z^3 + y^4;

wts = {1, 1, 2};
vars = {x, y, z};

Exponent[p /. Thread[vars -> (t*vars)^wts], t]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

This might be made into a function:

```
deg[vars_, wts_][poly_] /; Length[vars] == Length[wts] := 
  Module[{t}, Exponent[poly /. Thread[vars -> (t*vars)^wts], t]]

deg[{x, y, z}, {1, 1, 2}] /@
 {
   x^2 y + z^3 + y^4,
   x^2 y + y,
   x^2 y + z^3 - y^6
 }
```

> ```
> {6, 3, 6}
> ```

---

#### Old, unreliable answer

Second try, hopefully closer to what you need this time.

```
p = x^2 y + z^3 + y^4;
v = {x, y, z};
g = {1, 1, 2};

Exponent[p /. Thread[v -> E^g], E]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

```
Exponent[x^2 y + y /. Thread[v -> E^g], E]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

Incidentally the entire `Thread[v -> E^g]` may be unwanted but I tried to provide code that was more easily generalized, in case you have more variables or need to iterate over different weights, etc.

Comment: No, it doesn't answer the question:

take $p = x^2 y + y$, $deg(p) = 3$ but it's not what you compute....

Comment: @Smilia I am probably being obtuse or ignorant but would you please explain for me how the degree is 3 there?

Comment: Ok, here you go a definition in the preambule of the degree of multivariate polynomial:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial

Comment: @Smilia I don't know why but I overlooked your final line of code and made a bad guess as to how to use `g`.  I think I see what you want now?  I shall update my answer.  Please let me know.  If I still fail I'll delete this answer.

Comment: I would recommend using a new variable and just reweighting. That new variable should not be a built-in symbol such as `E`. `wts = {1, 1, 2};
vars = {x, y, z};
Exponent[p /. Thread[vars -> (t*vars)^wts], t]` Also, the method above will fail on `p = x^2 y + z^3 - y^6` (because it is not safe against cancellation of lead terms).

Comment: Also there is ``GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[p, {x, y, z}, 
   MonomialOrder -> Join[{wts}, NullSpace[{wts}]]][[1, 1, 1]].wts`` where `wts` is the weight vector. Requires that it be all nonnegative rationals, I think.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for coming to the rescue.